# Electromagnetic propulsion

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, kinematics

Is it possible to convert energy in magnetic field of a solenoid into acceleration of a magnet going through that solenoid ?

My experiment was to look at the effect of current intensity on the actual propulsion acceleration of the projectile. I used a magnet instead of a magnetic material as my projectile.

Comment: it is indeed. search for "electromagnetic rail gun" on wikipedia.

Comment: @nielsnielsen sorry for late reply and also thank you. Is this the same principle as my experiment ? Since the rail gun uses 2 wires (rails) and the projectile is perpendicular to the rails. But my experiment uses a solenoid, and the projectile (magnet) is "inside" the solenoid ...